# Filtering in pandas dataframe is not working

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to combine 3 CSV into one by using panda data frame. Consider below example

[image: data1.csv]
[image: data2.csv]
[image: data3.csv]

So I need to combine above the csv into one. This is implemented using below code

```
if os.path.isfile(data1.csv) and os.path.isfile(data2.csv) and os.path.isfile(data3.csv):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(data1.csv)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(data2.csv)
    df3 = pd.read_csv(data3.csv)
    self.combined_data_frame = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
    self.combined_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(self.combined_data_frame, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
    result = self.combined_data_frame.loc[(self.combined_data_frame['col3'] == 'FALSE')]
    result.to_csv(data4.csv)
```

Even though am able to combine the CSV into one, could not filter the rows based on the condition. When I tried above code snippet I got below warning and data4.csv does not contain anything except the headers

```
(venv) C:\Users\edward_arrow\path_to_location>python runscript.py
C:\Users\edward_arrow\path_to_location\venv\lib\site-packages\pa
ndas\core\computation\expressions.py:68: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison f
ailed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comp
arison
  return op(a, b)
```

May I know how can I resolve this issue in order to achieve my requirement or else is there any other method to implement using python.

Your  hints & solution are appreciated
#UPDATE
This is the excepted output
[image: final output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to find the files
- Use a list-comprehension with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to create a list of dataframe and combine them all with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

  - Note that `'FALSE'` and `'TRUE'` have been converted to `False` and `True` respectively, and are `bool`, not `str` type.
  - Alternatively, use `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'col3': str}) for file in files])`, which will maintain `col3` as a `str`, and then still filter for `'FALSE'`.
- Filter the dataframe with [Pandas: Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

  - The filter must filter for `False`, not `'FALSE'`.
- Save the dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)
- The current version of `pandas` is `1.1.0`.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

# find the files
files = Path('c:/users/some_path/to_files').glob('data*.csv')

# create a dataframe of all the files
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files]).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(df)
    col1  col2   col3
0      1     2  False
1      1     2  False
2      1     2   True
3      1     2  False
4      3     4  False
5      3     4   True
6      3     4   True
7      3     4   True
8      6     7  False
9      6     7  False
10     6     7  False
11     6     7  False

# filter the data for False
df_false = df[df.col3 == False]

# save the file
df_false.to_csv('false.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra set of parenthesis in the statement:

```
result = self.combined_data_frame.loc[(self.combined_data_frame['col3'] == 'FALSE')]
```

Try using this instead :

```
result = self.combined_data_frame.loc[self.combined_data_frame['col3'] == 'FALSE']
```

Comment: you want: `result = self.combined_data_frame.loc[~self.combined_data_frame['col3']]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will take this 3 DataFrame, concatenated them, and filter with **~** for col3:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
           'col1':[1,1,1,1],
           'col2':[2,2,2,2], 
           'col3':[False, True, False, True]
         })
print(df1)
   col1  col2   col3
0     1     2  False
1     1     2   True
2     1     2  False
3     1     2   True

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
           'col1':[3,3,3,3],
           'col2':[4,4,4,4], 
           'col3':[False, True, True, True]
         })
print(df2)
   col1  col2   col3
0     3     4  False
1     3     4   True
2     3     4   True
3     3     4   True

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
           'col1':[6,6,6,6],
           'col2':[7,7,7,7], 
           'col3':[False, False, False, False]
         })
print(df3)
   col1  col2   col3
0     6     7  False
1     6     7  False
2     6     7  False
3     6     7  False

combined_data_frame = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
print(combined_data_frame)
    col1  col2   col3
0      1     2  False
1      1     2   True
2      1     2  False
3      1     2   True
4      3     4  False
5      3     4   True
6      3     4   True
7      3     4   True
8      6     7  False
9      6     7  False
10     6     7  False
11     6     7  False

final_data_frame = combined_data_frame[~combined_data_frame.col3]
print(final_data_frame)
    col1  col2   col3
0      1     2  False
2      1     2  False
4      3     4  False
8      6     7  False
9      6     7  False
10     6     7  False
11     6     7  False

final_data_frame.to_csv('final_data_frame.csv', index=False)
```

The final file is according your expected output (**index=False**).